# Converting JSON to Python dictionary (looking for a better way to do it)

Tags: json, python-3.x

So I already wrote this code that works, but it feels like there must be a better way to do it:

```
# json_data is a passed in JSON object
str_json = str(json_data)
# convert the string to python dictionary
new_dict = json.loads(str_json)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is your friend.

```
json.loads
```

is the method you should use. It's the best way.

Comment: Oh, so converting to a string wasn't even needed.  Good to know!